# Implement protocol variable conforming to single protocol as variable conforming to several protocols

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to do a simple thing, but the code gives an error: *Type 'MyClass' does not conform to protocol 'MyProtocol3'*.

```
protocol MyProtocol1 {

}

protocol MyProtocol2 {

}

protocol MyProtocol3 {
    var output: MyProtocol2 { get }
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol3 {

    var output: MyProtocol2 & MyProtocol1

    init(output: MyProtocol1 & MyProtocol2) {
        self.output = output
    }
}
```

Conforming MyProtocol2 to MyProtocol1 also doesn't do the trick. Is it possible to use variable conforming to multiple protocol as another protocol var?

Comment: It doesn't conform because `MyClass` doesn't satisfy the requirement of `MyProtocol3`. It's too restrictive in that it wants `output` to also conform to `MyProtocol1`, whereas `MyProtocol3` allows for it not to

Answer (score 0):

You say, "Conforming MyProtocol2 to MyProtocol1 also doesn't do the trick."  Unless you have some trick in mind that you haven't mentioned, it looks to me like the answer.

The following works in a playground:

```
protocol MyProtocol1 {
    func test1()
}

protocol MyProtocol2: MyProtocol1 {
    func test2()
}

class OutputClass: MyProtocol2 {
    func test1() {
        print("test1")
    }
    func test2() {
        print("test2")
    }
}

protocol MyProtocol3 {
    var output: MyProtocol2 { get }
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol3 {

    var output: MyProtocol2

    init(output: MyProtocol2) {
        self.output = output
    }
}

let o = OutputClass()
o.test1()
o.test2()
let m = MyClass(output: o)
```